# Define string for name of button android?

Tags: android, string, button

I get problem about define string for name of button  android ?

```
//Initial name button
Button btn_favorite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite);

//condition 
String Count_Favorite = "Count favorite";

//replace string for define name btn_favorite
String name_btn = Count_Favorite .replace("Count ", "btn_");

//(this, name_btn) this part i get problem              
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, name_btn);
badge.setText("0");
badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
badge.show();
```

the bold is my problem >>

```
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, **name_btn**);
```

in my code **name_btn** is String **Format**, I will to define this for name of button **btn_favorite**, but is error.

So how to define string for **name_btn** of button  **btn_favorite** ?

this image  of the code error , with my implemention:

[image]

**BadgeView** is like this

[image]

check this >> https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: Very unclear!! Please elaborate..

Comment: this not unclear in my code, please tell me...

Comment: What exactly you want to do? And what is `nama`?

Comment: What is the `Badgeview` ?? Is that `class` written by you or you have copied from any API?

Comment: What are input params for BadgeView.. just hover your mouse over BadgeView and you will know.. Or just hover your mouse at error sign and post the statement in the question itself..

Comment: @Rapunzel : sorry i edited my question ; nama is Count_Favorite ;
i want to define button name from the string...

Comment: Name for button or text for button?

Comment: I think the `BadgeView` accepts `this`[the context] and a `View`.

Try Something Like this :
`int id = getResources().getIdentifier(nama_btn, "id", context.getPackageName());`

`View view = findViewById(id);`

then, `BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, view);`

If I am correct about the source of `BadgeView`, this should work, though no surety because of the source of your `BadgeView` is still unknown.

Comment: @CRUSADER BadgeView used for like show notification view ... check this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: @Rapunzel name of button

Comment: I think @Writwick comment will solve the problem, BadgeView in fact takes second param as View.. try that..

Comment: thank you @Writwick Its work ... great.. :D .

All : oh my reputation is down :D ..
but thank you for all participation has answered my question :)

Comment: @bukanamay You can add your solution as an answer to this question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOlVED**

with this code

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(nama_btn, "id", context.getPackageName()); 
View view = findViewById(id); BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, view);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the constructor of `BadgeView`, if you see, 2nd argument is `View`, not a `String`.

```
public BadgeView(Context context, View target) {

    this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target, 0);

}
```

Please, check and modify your code accordingly. You are passing `String` object as a argument for `BadgeView`.